# Paypal Smart Button – Delay firing "onApproval" causes issues

Tags: javascript, paypal

Using the Smart Payment buttons, there is a 3-4 second delay after the payment pop-up window closes. It takes 3-4 seconds after the close of the transaction window to fire the onApproval event which gets the transaction ID needed to process an order.

**This causes trouble** as the buyer could close the window in the meantime (as nothing seems to happen) and the event is never received, thus the order not processed (although paid for).

Here is the code:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data,actions) {
    // do some stuff
        return fetch('/createOrder', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data.orderID;
        });
    },

    // onApprove will be fired 3-4 second AFTER the popup of transaction closes
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('captureOrder', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID:data.orderID
            })
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(details) {     
        });
    }

}).render(selector);
```

**Is there any way to have the popup close AFTER the even is fired?** Otherwise the only work-around would be to make an overlay with a spinner (or something similar) that will disappear once the onApproval is received. But that is cumbersome. The pop-up really shouldn't close before the event is fired.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually the firing of this event that is “delayed”, and that it is not your fetch request that takes the time?

Comment: Yeah, it's normal for the underlying server-side capture API call of the fetch to take 2+ seconds. So in fact, prior to the fetch you could display some status

Comment: Ahh, that's a valid point – I will look into this. This would mean that as soon as the pop closes I WILL have the transaction ID I need. Makes sense.

Comment: You actually won't get it until the fetch completes, but you will be in the JS code above the fetch sooner

Answer (score 2):

I haven't observed that long of a delay myself, and it shouldn't cause issues as the buyer should wait for their confirmation in any case, but well it is as it is.

You can use the `onClick` method to trigger a please wait / spinner or whatever if you feel it's necessary, and nuke it within your onApprove's fetch (and also an onError and onCancel function). But you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: I actually do this now the "overcomplicated way" as I feel that it is a better user experience to see a "progress indicator" after the pop closes rather than seeing nothing and wondering why there has not been an update.

Comment: I put a "Processing, please wait" overlay within `onApprove` but that only made the overlay appear after the wait, so it didn't really work for me. What helped was putting the overlay within `createOrder`. It activates straight after creating an order and stays under the check-out window (not really seen unless you move the window), and then once the transaction is approved, the check-out window closes and the overlay is already there. Then the overlay disappears once the user is redirected to a "Thank you" page. Maybe not the nicest solution but I think it gives a better user experience.

Comment: ^Possibly okay if only using the 'PayPal' button, but not good in conjunction with the black 'Debit or Credit Card' one

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
        // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

        // When ready to go live, remove the alert and show a success message within this page. For example:
        // var element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
        // element.innerHTML = '';
        // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
        // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
      });
    }
```