# Paypal Smart Buttons V2 and IPN - How to match fields from Smart Buttons to IPN

Tags: javascript, php, button, paypal, paypal-ipn

Problem: I am using the integration from Papal Smart Buttons as Checkout V2 on the client site. The Problem is, that Users on the Website are not waiting long enough after payment completed. They just click further and my website can not process the transaction right on my database.

1. User click on Payment Smart Button
2. Paypal Framework opens
3. User do the Payment
4. User will go automatically back to the website
5. Payal need around 2 Second, bevor sending approval of transaction to may website.
6. User not waiting and clicking further, so my script can not catching the approval and do not insert any Payment data to my Database.
7. Result: User complaining to my support, the got nothing after his Payment was done.

I know there are some different Solution like IPN and Webhooks. But the documentation and Sandbox from PayPal is so confusing. I really hate the documentation from PayPal.

Like described - I am using Smart Buttons and trying to send some values thru it and match them on the IPN. As a result, I could catch the transaction on ipn, if the user do not wait on the client site. But there is a Problem! What references or fields are matching together from the Smart buttons fields to the IPN fields???? ... I could not find anything in the documentation, which fields matches and which do not!

Smart Button Example

I tried the fields like: reference_id, invoice_id or sku, but no one of are showing up on the IPN fields?

```
      return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    reference_id: 35 ,
                    description: "test", 
                    custom_id: user_id, 
                    invoice_id: 35,
                    amount: {
                        currency_code: "EUR",
                        value: 100,
                        breakdown: {
                            item_total: {
                                currency_code: "EUR",
                                value: 100
                            }
                        } 
                    }, 
                    items: [{
                        name: "test1",
                        description: "test2",
                        sku: 35,
                        unit_amount: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: 100
                        },
                        quantity: "1"
                    }],
                }],
            });
```

IPN Example:

```
mc_gross=12.35 &
custom=96494 & 
item_name=test &
transaction_subject=test &

protection_eligibility=Eligible & 
address_status=confirmed & 
payer_id=VY7TCC2&GHJ & 
address_street=Kaiserstraße 14 & 
payment_date=01:05:28 Sep 25, 2020 PDT & 
payment_status=Completed & 
charset=windows-1252 & 
address_zip=79067 & 
first_name=Alex & 
mc_fee=0.63 & 
address_country_code=DE & 
address_name=Alex Boxman & 
notify_version=3.9 & 

payer_status=verified & 
business=paypal@test.de & 
address_country=Germany & 
address_city=Freiburg im Breisgau & 
quantity=1 & 
verify_sign=sqlgasdfs.uUsakasdfasdfbS3YeaE9V5 & 
payer_email=test@gmail.com & 
txn_id=96255345678 & 
payment_type=instant & 
last_name=Boxman & 
address_state= & 
receiver_email=paypal@test.de & 
payment_fee= & 
shipping_discount=0.00 & 
insurance_amount=0.00 & 
receiver_id=M7VC&FGHHJL & 
txn_type=express_checkout & 

discount=0.00 & 
mc_currency=EUR & 
item_number= & 
residence_country=DE & 
shipping_method=Default &  
 
payment_gross= & 
ipn_track_id=24asdfsfsfds
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to be using a legacy product like IPN with smart payment buttons and v2 APIs.

Instead, use a proper server integration. You'll need two routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction', and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Once you have those two routes, the UI to pair with them is https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: This is not working, because there is still time to click further, it takes 1-3 sec after payment was done for a response (on Approval) from PayPal. At this time every User can just click further. It does not matter if you use a Server integration or client integration.

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything. When the capture occurs on your server, your server receives the response to matter what, and so you never lose track of whether the order was placed or not. The user's browser's client-side behavior is irrelevant, there's nothing you can do about that, no matter what -- in fact, that is precisely the reason you should use the server integration, so you are not dependent on what they do.

Comment: There are other people with the same issue. You can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890806/paypal-smart-button-delay-firing-onapproval-causes-issues